# Doesn't look like an automorphism to me...

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am self-studying algebra using Dummit and Foote.  One early exercise asks me to prove that for each fixed nonzero $k \in \mathbb{Q}$, the map $\varphi:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ defined as $\varphi(q) = kq$ is an automorphism.  It's certainly a bijection, but I am having difficulty persuading myself it is a homomorphism.  For let $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$.  Then 
\begin{align}
\varphi(pq) & = kpq
\end{align}
while
\begin{align}
\varphi(p)\varphi(q) & = k^2pq,
\end{align} 
and unless $k = 1$, these are not equal.  Evidently I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: The group you're asked to do prove should be $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and not $(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\},\times)$?

Comment: You are right, this is not a $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism if we're talking about field automorphisms. Maybe they were talking about group automorphisms if you see  $\mathbb{Q}$ as a group under addition.

Comment: Well, that's clearly the obvious thing I was missing.  Thanks, all.

Comment: As a group, under addition, this is an automorphism, since scalar multiplication distributes over addition, etc. However, you're correct in that it is **not** a homomorphism when lookin gat $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ under multiplication, since for any $k\ne 1,$ we have $k1\ne 1,$ and so it does not preserve the identity of $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the question implicitly means for the semigroup operation to be addition, not multiplication.